# Transfer the colors of a face from a photo inside a drawing

Tags: style-transfer

I have a photo of a real person.
I have a  colorized picture of a resembling person (same angle, different lighting and colors, drawing look alike)

I would like to transfer the colors of the photo inside the drawing. (To be exactly the same colors), so that the drawing would look like a photo. How can I do that ?

Thank you for your ideas